# Is a proper morphism of schemes open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, open-map

I am wondering whether a proper morphism of schemes, which is closed by definition, has to be open. Since nobody told me this I suspect it to be false, but I can't find a counter-example. Could anyone help me (just hints are very welcome too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any closed immersion is finite, hence proper, and is never open unless it surjects onto a connected component of the target. From this you can get a plethora of counterexamples.

Comment: It's not quite true that it's "never open unless it's surjective"--what if the base scheme is disconnected?

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, fixed!